# exit awk if pattern matched

Tags: awk, exit

I was wondering if I could tell awk to stop searching for pattern 1 to pattern 2 after the first encounter. Because the file I am scanning contains 4 GB of text and each repetition of the awk command takes like a minute to compute and I have to do it a million times. LITERALLY a million times.

the line I'm trying to optimize goes like this:

```
awk "/MODEL        ${j}/,/ENDMDL/" j=$j filename.pdb > outputfile.txt
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: why not use `grep --max-count=NUM` ?

Comment: This might be a better question for http://superuser.com/

Comment: You can use sed: `sed  '/patternA/,/patternB/!d;/patternB/q' filename.pdb > outputfile.txt`, this might be faster than awk.

Comment: thank you very much captcha works just fine takes less than a second now!

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
awk '/MODEL/,/ENDMDL/;/ENDMDL/{exit}' mybigfile
```

With `sed`:

```
sed -n '/MODEL/,/ENDMDL/p;/ENDMDL/q' mybigfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the /start/,/end/ pattern, it just makes your life harder when you need to do anything other than the basics. Try this instead:

```
awk -v j="$j" '$0 ~ "MODEL        " j{f=1} f; f&&/ENDMDL/{exit}' filename.pdb
```